# can I return to a previous line in the code in a for loop? R

Tags: r

I am running a code with a very large `for` loop. Within that large loop, I have a second `for` loop that carries out some checks. If one of those checks is not satisfactory, I am using `break` to stop the second loop, but instead of continuing with the rest of the lines below, I want the code to go back to the line corresponding to the beginning of the first `for` loop and carry on the analysis with the next index. Is this possible?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example with some code and data as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It is possible to do what you describe. There may also be a way of writing the code so it is not necessary.

Comment: You could wrap the rest of the second loop in a conditional that is skipped when the condition that triggers the break occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sentinel value:

```r
for (OL in ...) {
  # do something
  next_OL <- FALSE         # always set this before entering the inner loop
  for (IL in ...) {
    # do something else
    if (some_condition) {
      next_OL <- TRUE
      break                # breaks out of inner loop "IL"
    }
  }
  if (next_OL) next        # breaks out of outer loop "OL"
  # perhaps do more here
}
```

Comment: The sentinel value did the work accurately. Cheers for the suggestion

Comment: just realised that what I was actually looking for was ```break``` for the inner loop, and then ```next``` for the outer one